# Java program for detecting server login prompt?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm writing a program in Java to automate a web test of server management console URL's to find which ones present users with a box for login credentials.

I have begun looking into doing this with Selenium WebDriver to automate the actual test function of opening and closing windows, but what I can't figure out is how I should go about detecting whether or not the login box is presented to a user.

Is there a specific response code that the server presents when this happens? I know when a user is unauthenticated/forbidden there will be an HTTP response of 401 or 403, respectively, but I am not sure if this 401 unauthenticated response Code will happen regardless of whether or not a box for login credentials is presented to the user.

The goal is to find which URL's allowed a user the opportunity to type in credentials and then publish those to a .txt file for further evaluation.  I already have the java I/O elements working properly to do this, so all I really need is to figure out what condition I'm looking for.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Selenium is primarily about web browser automation, not HTTP codes. With Seleinum you could probe for the existence of the login box for each URL you want to check. You could do it by using `WebDriver.findElements` or `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated`. If you provide the code you've got so far, I could go into more detail.

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick.

Comment: Nice to know. The best way to say this, is accepting the answer. You even get reputation for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have an instantiated WebDriver instance (`driver`) 
and a collection of URLs (`urls`) you want to check, 
and given your loginbox contains some element located by ID "username"

then *one possible* Selenium solution in Java could look like this:

```
for (String url : urls) {
    driver.get(url);
    //adjust to your needs: long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120L, 1000L);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
        //TODO: Element found within timeOutInSeconds
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        //TODO: Element not present after timeOutInSeconds, write url to txt file
    }
}
```

If you cannot locate the element by id, use other locating mechanisms as [described here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html).